# breezejs: Where do I set AutoGeneratedKeyType

Tags: javascript, breeze

I use WCF ODATA, so AutoGeneratedKeyType is not set by breeze and I have to do it manually.

I know I can do :

```
var et = new breeze.EntityType({
 shortName: "TodoItem",
 namespace: "NoDb.Models",
 autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity
});
```

but in my case, the entity is defined on the server and I get all the metadata from $metadata. I'm only missing AutoGeneratedKeyType, which I want to set to Identity.

How can I do that, without having to redefine the entity on the client side ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the *entityType* from the *metadataStore* and then call *setProperties* on it. Something like:

```
 var regionType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Region");
 regionType.setProperties({ autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity });
```